# I'm looking for an alternative to SUMIFS for text using tables

Tags: excel

I currently have an issue wherein I can't return text from a table. In order to return something like date of birth, I have no issues as it is a number, the formula I use for that is as follows.

```
=SUMIFS(tblEmployees[Date of Birth],tblEmployees[List of Employees],tblLeave[[#This Row],[Employee Name]])
```

This is returning numbers perfectly but is useless for text, I've tried using arrays but I could have been using it wrong. In an ideal world where SUMIFS returns text, my formula would have been as follows.

```
=SUMIFS(tblEmployees[Department],tblEmployees[List of Employees],tblLeave[[#This Row],[Employee Name]])
```

tblEmployees and tblLeave are on different sheets as well but the data is being called into the same sheet as tblLeave.

Any help would be great.

I would like to return text from the column Department within tblEmployees, identifying the row using the name of the employee using the employee name. The identifying of the row and column is working, as shown by it returning numbers but I need a function that will allow me to return text in the same manner as SUMIFS returns numbers.

Comment: It will be a very strange world if functions like SUM or SUMIF start returning text.... :) What, exactly, you want the formula to do?

Comment: Realised that I didn't make the question too easy to see, have edited.

Comment: It is working for numbers because there is only one match, or the return will be the sum of all numeric. In both cases you should use match to return the row and index to the return the value you want (in the row returned by match)

Comment: I have the column through 

=COLUMN(tblEmployees[Department])

and the row using

=MATCH(tblLeave[[#This Row],[Employee Name]],tblEmployees[List of Employees])

but I have no idea how to get the text returning.

Comment: If you have row number and column number use index....INDEX(range, row, column)

Comment: I just get a #REF error with.........

=INDEX(tblEmployees, MATCH(tblLeave[[#This Row],[Employee Name]],tblEmployees[List of Employees])+3, COLUMN(tblEmployees[Department]))

Comment: Unfortunately not pnuts, can't input a custom row in that function.

Comment: Absolutely perfect pnuts, if you want to submit it as an answer, I'll mark it as good. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain why a relatively simple:

```
=tblEmployees[[#This Row],[Department]]
```

did not suit in this case, so mention that in case suitable for someone else, but it seems:

```
=INDEX(tblEmployees[Department],MATCH(tblLeave[[#This Row],[Employee name]],tblEmployees[List of Employees],0))
```

serves the purpose.